# hasMany timing out when retrieving belongsTo models

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5.1, has-many, belongs-to

From this [Laravel 5.1](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) documentation, it seems I can override the `foreign_key` and `local_key` with the following on a HasMany relationship:

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```

I changed the foreign keys in my `belongsTo` model `NpcTarget` from `npc_id` to `npc_id_fk`. So therefore, I changed the relationship to:

```
public function npc()
{                            
    return $this->belongsTo(Npc::class, 'npc_id_fk', 'id');
}
```

`npc_id_fk` references the foreign key id of `npc`, and `id` is the actual name of the column in `npc`.

**My goal** is to load the `quest` with its `task` with its `npc` with its `npctarget`. Running my own query works as expected:

```
select n.id, nt.id from npcs n inner join npcstarget nt on (n.id = nt.npc_id_fk);
```

**Problem**: Given the relationships below, when I run this, the browser times out. I get error:

> FatalErrorException in QueryCollector.php line 0:
>
> Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

Yet if I change to `return $this->belongsTo(Npc::class, 'npc_id_fk', 'npc_id');`, it runs query `where "npcstarget"."npc_id_fk" in ('')`. Why is the browser timing out?

---

Hitting the following route with `NpcTarget` relationship defined as `$this->belongsTo(Npc::class, 'npc_id_fk', 'npc_id');`:

```
Route::get('/quest', function () {
    $quest = Quest::findOrFail(1)->get();
});
```

I get **DebugBar output:**

```
select * from "quests" where "quests"."id" = '1' limit 1
select * from "tasks" where "tasks"."quest_id" in ('1')
select "npcs".*, "task_npcs"."task_id" as "pivot_task_id", "task_npcs"."npc_id" as "pivot_npc_id" from "npcs" inner join "task_npcs" on "npcs"."id" = "task_npcs"."npc_id" where "task_npcs"."task_id" in ('1', '2', '3')
select * from "npcstarget" where "npcstarget"."npc_id_fk" in ('')
```

Hitting that same route with `NpcTarget` relationship defined as `$this->belongsTo(Npc::class, 'npc_id_fk', 'id');`, it times out with no query outputs.

**Models:**

Quest:

```
class Quest extends BaseModel
{
    protected $with = ['tasks'];

    public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
    }
    ...
}
```

Task:

```
class Task extends BaseModel
{
    protected $with = ['npcs'];

    public function npcs()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Npc::class, 'task_npcs');
    }
    ...
}
```

Npc:

```
class Npc extends BaseModel
{
    protected $with = ['npcstarget'];

    public function npcstarget()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(NpcTarget::class, 'npc_id_fk', 'id');
    }
}
```

NpcTarget:

```
class NpcTarget extends Npc
{
    protected $table = 'npcstarget';

    public function npc()
    {
        // If this: Times out
        return $this->belongsTo(Npc::class, 'npc_id_fk', 'id');

        // If this: Shows above "where "npcstarget"."npc_id_fk" in ('')"
        return $this->belongsTo(Npc::class, 'npc_id_fk', 'npc_id');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the error was having `NpcTarget` extending `Npc`

```
class NpcTarget extends Npc
{
    protected $table = 'npcstarget';

    public function npc()
    {
        // If this: Times out
        return $this->belongsTo(Npc::class, 'npc_id_fk', 'id');
    }
}
```

Changing it to `class NpcTarget extends BaseModel` works.

I'm guessing this is because extending `Npc` calls another `with` query on the `NpcTarget`, creating an infinite loop.

I'd still like to extend a parent model to get some of its properties.

Comment: Have you tried profiling it with Blackfire? Does `npc_id_fk` have an index?